# Can anyone identify this reposted artwork of a Grey alien?

Tags: aliens, horror, character-identification, art, ufos

[image: Grey, grainy image of Grey alien regularly reposted online]

I love spooky paranormal stuff (though I don't believe a lick of it) and am curious to know the origins of this eerie illustration of a Grey alien. I've seen it reposted online a lot, but with no source.

To narrow down the sources, it is NOT:

- Ted Seth Jacob's painting for Whitley Strieber's Communion https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/ce/Communion_book_cover.jpg
- any of Kesara's UFO artwork (as far as I can tell, as her art has a slightly amateurish quality, but correct me if I'm wrong)
- this reposted behind the scenes image of one of the animatronics used for Intruders (1992) https://pbs.twimg.com/media/ECg0tlpW4AIkOYU.jpg

I tried reverse image searching but I just got gibberish results and more reposts. Would love to know the source image!

Comment: The image is from at least 2003; https://web.archive.org/web/20030414201847/http://www.spacejay.com/Special%20Research/Alienworlds%20Infobase/Apex/Apex.htm - It was posted alongside this other photo - https://web.archive.org/web/20030414201847im_/http://www.spacejay.com/Special%20Research/Alienworlds%20Infobase/Apex/Grey-2.jpg

Comment: UFOs and paranormal stuff are off topic here unless they are in works of fiction.

Comment: @user14111 - This image is almost exclusively used to illustrate "real" encounters with aliens, although I've seen it on various movie sites as a placeholder image

Comment: @user14111; Aren't all depictions of aliens, at this point, science fiction?  The "science" bit is that alien lifeforms might well exist.  The fiction comes from there being, essentially, no scientific proof of that existence, and certainly no proof that they are visiting the Earth or seriously need to increase their vitamin D intake.

Comment: @user14111 yeah but as JohnHunt said, it may as well be science-fiction, and with a lot of these reposted images, they tend to originate and overlap with science-fiction art proper. Hence bringing up the Intruders animatronic that is always reposted in articles about UFOs/Greys. The image Im trying to identify could be concept art from a game/movie for all I know

Comment: @Valorum that other photo I notice always gets reposted endlessly too, with zero credit either. Kinda wish I could find a source for that one too

Answer (score 10):

I think I've finally managed to identify this, thanks to the wayback machine crawl that was posted earlier.

This is '[*Anatomy of a Sky Creature*](https://www.artnet.com/artists/rod-dickinson/anatomy-of-a-sky-creature-t7q21DvSVhFAXUp-Dt_8-Q2)' by British artist [Rod Dickinson](https://www.artnet.com/artists/rod-dickinson/), but edited to be in black and white, and slightly compressed.

[image]

Comment: Fantastic work, and worthy of an additional reward :-)